# Receiving RawInput from touchscreen in net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, hid

I have an external hid touchscreen and i want to receive the rawinput data in my application.
My application is just a console application and i want to create a window, so that i can use the handle to register a rawinputdevice.

I created a window like this:

```
namespace MyApplication
{

   delegate IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    class Win32Window
    {
        const UInt32 WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW = 0xcf0000;
        const UInt32 WS_VISIBLE = 0x10000000;
        const UInt32 CS_USEDEFAULT = 0x80000000;
        const UInt32 CS_DBLCLKS = 8;
        const UInt32 CS_VREDRAW = 1;
        const UInt32 CS_HREDRAW = 2;
        const UInt32 COLOR_WINDOW = 5;
        const UInt32 COLOR_BACKGROUND = 1;
        const UInt32 IDC_CROSS = 32515;
        const UInt32 WM_DESTROY = 2;
        const UInt32 WM_PAINT = 0x0f;
        const UInt32 WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;
        const UInt32 WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x0203;
        const UInt32 WM_INPUT = 0x00FF;

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        struct WNDCLASSEX
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
            public int cbSize;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
            public int style;
            public IntPtr lpfnWndProc; 
            public int cbClsExtra;
            public int cbWndExtra;
            public IntPtr hInstance;
            public IntPtr hIcon;
            public IntPtr hCursor;
            public IntPtr hbrBackground;
            public string lpszMenuName;
            public string lpszClassName;
            public IntPtr hIconSm;
        }


        private WndProc delegWndProc = myWndProc;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool UpdateWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool DestroyWindow(IntPtr hWnd);


        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "CreateWindowEx")]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateWindowEx(
           int dwExStyle,
           UInt16 regResult,
           //string lpClassName,
           string lpWindowName,
           UInt32 dwStyle,
           int x,
           int y,
           int nWidth,
           int nHeight,
           IntPtr hWndParent,
           IntPtr hMenu,
           IntPtr hInstance,
           IntPtr lpParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "RegisterClassEx")]
        static extern System.UInt16 RegisterClassEx([In] ref WNDCLASSEX lpWndClass);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern uint GetLastError();

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr DefWindowProc(IntPtr hWnd, uint uMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern void PostQuitMessage(int 

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr LoadCursor(IntPtr hInstance, int lpCursorName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool TranslateMessage([In] ref MSG lpMsg);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr DispatchMessage([In] ref MSG lpmsg);    


        internal bool Create()
        {
            WNDCLASSEX wind_class = new WNDCLASSEX();
            wind_class.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WNDCLASSEX));
            wind_class.style = (int)(CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_DBLCLKS ) ; //Doubleclicks are active
            wind_class.hbrBackground = (IntPtr) COLOR_BACKGROUND  +1 ; //Black background, +1 is necessary
            wind_class.cbClsExtra = 0;
            wind_class.cbWndExtra = 0;
            wind_class.hInstance = Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(this.GetType().Module); ;// alternative: Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle;
            wind_class.hIcon = IntPtr.Zero;
            wind_class.hCursor = LoadCursor(IntPtr.Zero, (int)IDC_CROSS);// Crosshair cursor;
            wind_class.lpszMenuName = null;
            wind_class.lpszClassName = "myClass";
            wind_class.lpfnWndProc = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(delegWndProc);
            wind_class.hIconSm = IntPtr.Zero;
            ushort regResult = RegisterClassEx(ref wind_class);

            if (regResult == 0)
            {
                uint error = GetLastError();
                return false;
            }
            string wndClass = wind_class.lpszClassName;

            IntPtr hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, regResult, "Hello Win32", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, 300, 400, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, wind_class.hInstance, IntPtr.Zero);

            if (hWnd == ((IntPtr)0))
            {
                uint error = GetLastError();
                return false;
            }
            ShowWindow(hWnd, 1);
            UpdateWindow(hWnd);
            return true;
        }

        private static IntPtr myWndProc(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            switch (msg)
            {
                case WM_INPUT:
                    // Get RawInput Data and do some stuff
                    break;
                case WM_PAINT:
                    break;

                case WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK :
                    Console.WriteLine("Doubleclick");
                    break;

                case WM_DESTROY:
                    DestroyWindow(hWnd);

                    //If you want to shutdown the application, call the next function instead of DestroyWindow
                    //PostQuitMessage(0);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
}
```

I used the handle of this window to register a rawinputdevice, which is successful. Some windows messages are processed to the window, but not the wm_input messages.
If i get these messages, i want to hide the window, because i don't need it.

If somebody knows an other way to get the data from an external touchscreen in net core, feel free to post it.